# How to write multiple python lists into an excel file using xlwt package?

Tags: python, xlwt

I am reading a tab delimited text file into python list and now I want to have the list items into excel file. The snapshot of my text file is given below

```
BGIOSGA014473   0.955233    0.271947    3.5125704641    1.81252716688   Upregulated
BGIOSGA000577   0.219720    0.118096    1.86052025471   0.895706096568  Upregulated
BGIOSGA019391   0.959914    0.037380    25.67988229 4.68256668442   Upregulated
EPlOING00000022268  0.514413    0.701827    0.732962681687  -0.448188348529 Downregulated
BGIOSGA024514   0.481147    0.058495    8.22543807163   3.04009251617   Upregulated
```

[i wanted it to be in this excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVb98.png)

What I have tried is this

```
import xlwt
style0 = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index red, bold on')
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
ws = wb.add_sheet('test')

with open("out.txt") as outfile:
    for line in outfile:
        line=line.strip().split("\t")
        for i in range():
            for i,e in enumerate(line):
                ws.write(i,1,e)
wb.save('test.xls')
```

However, I am not getting it. I am missing how to change the row. Can anybody help

Comment: Try this:
Open excel-> open the text file-> select the delimiter as "Tab".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your question:

1. your code do not update row index
2. `ws.write()` parameter is `(row, col, val)`
3. `range()` need a argument

---

Here is a  working sample.

```python
import xlwt
style0 = xlwt.easyxf('font: name Times New Roman, color-index red, bold on')
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
ws = wb.add_sheet('test')

with open("data.txt") as outfile:
    row = 0
    for line in outfile:
        line = line.strip().split("\t")
        for col, val in enumerate(line):
            ws.write(row, col, val)
        row = row + 1

wb.save('data.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using pandas for this. The code is as easy as

```
import pandas as pd
```

create a pandas dataframe using `df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_for_data)`

```
df.to_excel(path)
```